# Why aren't my throw exception being caught locally

Tags: javascript, exception, uncaught-exception

My code wont run the throws that should be caught in the exception, why is this? Here is the code I'm running

```
function butCalculate_onclick() {
try {
    if (window.top.calcFactorial == null)
        throw "This page is not loaded within the correct frameset";
    if (document.form1.txtNum1.value == "")
        throw "!Please enter a value before you calculate its factorial";
    if (isNaN(document.form1.txtNum1.value))
        throw "!Please enter a valid number";
    if (document.form1.txtNum1.value < 0)
        throw "!Please enter a positive number";
    else {document.form1.txtResult.value = window.parent.calcFactorial(document.form1.txtNum1.value);}
}
catch (exception) {
    if (typeof (exception) == "string") {
        if (exception.chartAt(0) == "!") {
            alert(exception.substr(1));
            document.form1.txtNum1.focus();
            document.form1.txtNum1.select();
        }
        else {
            alert(exception);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("the following error occurred "+ exception.message);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is happening, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ssube Fixed the title. The throw's are NOT being caught

Comment: You should probably refactor your code to actually throw exceptions (`throw new Error`) instead of string literals, then check to see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure the throw conditions are being met? Try setting a flag instead of throwing, and check if its set.

Comment: [Don't Use Exceptions as Flow Control](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)